# How to reuse PHPUnit functions

Tags: laravel-4, phpunit

I want to reuse some of my PHPUnit functions by calling them instead of repeating them in all unit tests, such as this for example:

```
public function testContent()
    {
        $this->assertNotEmpty($this->response, $this->message);
    }
```

If I place it under tests/TestCase.php, it runs for all the unit tests.

Where would be the right place to put this or how is this usually done? Btw, I am using it on Laravel 4.

Comment: Generally, unit tests should have relevant assertions. Check the content of the response, and the specific differences you expect when setting up the different scenarios, rather than it being not empty.

Comment: @jedifans I don't see any problems to make your own assertions

Comment: Making your own is fine but repeatedly asserting the same assertion for each test indicates the tests don't vary what they are setting up. As every collaborator is/should be mocked out, there should only be a few explicit cases where the response could be empty.

Comment: @jedifans You are talking about classical unit-testing. Meanwhile, PHPUnit could be perfectly used for integration tests, and in this case, you might want to ensure that all your vital pages of application are generated correctly.

Comment: @jedifans : given code was just an example. i am testing for relevant things in most of my unit tests. things like cache, not empty, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, your problem is not to re-use tests, but that your tests are beeing called when it's not expected.

So, have in your mind: any method with a name starting with "test" (testFoo, testBar) in an existing class will be considered as a test.

So if you have classes A, B and C like this

```
class A extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   public function testFoo() {...}
   public function testBar() {...}
}

class B extends A {
   public function testBaz() {...}
}

class C extends A {
   public function testQuz() {...}
}
```

you will have 8 tests: A::testFoo(), A::testBar(), B::testFoo(), B::testBar(), B::testBaz(), C::testFoo(), C::testBar(), C::testQuz().

It's probably is not what you was trying to make.
You may want to have testFoo and testBar only in classes B and C, not it A. In this case, you just have to declare A as an abstract class.

```
abstract class A extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   public function testFoo() {...}
   public function testBar() {...}
}

class B extends A {
   public function testBaz() {...}
}

class C extends A {
   public function testQuz() {...}
}
```

Now you have 6 tests: B::testFoo(), B::testBar(), B::testBaz(), C::testFoo(), C::testBar(), C::testQuz().

Maybe, it's what you need, maybe not. Maybe, you want to have testFoo() and testBar() only in **some** inherited classes, not all of them.

In this case, make assertions in you parent class instead of tests.

```
abstract class A extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   public function assertFoo() { ... }
   public function assertBar() { ... }
}

class B extends A {
   public function testFoo() { $this->assertFoo(); ...}

   public function testBaz() {...}
}

class C extends A {
   public function testBar() { $this->assertBar(); ...}

   public function testQuz() {...}
}
```

Now, you have only 4 tests: B::testFoo(), B::testBaz, C::testBar(), C::testQuz()

Comment: thanks alot, trying it now. I needed your last piece of code. just one thing, assertFoo() and assertBar in class A will have implementation right? not empty methods?

Comment: Sure. It's the main goal after all - to avoid code repetition. P.S. Do not forget to mark answer as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your own assertion according [to this manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html)

Make something like

```
namespace Vendor\Library\Tests;

abstract class BaseTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   public function assertContentNotEmpty($response) {
       $this->assertNotEmpty($response);
   }
}
```

And then extend this class with your tests.
If this approach is not convenient for some reasons, you can make an assertion as a separate class.

Comment: how about the setUp, tearDown and other methods, i would need to repeat them again? also, how is it different from putting in TestCase, won't it run for all tests? sorry, new to phpunit.

Comment: what do you mean by "run for all tests?" It will be run only when you call in some test $this->assertNotEmpty($response). setUp, tearDown need no to be defined in parent class, but you may do it if you want to re-use something from test to test.

Comment: currently, my unit tests are extending TestCase.php. my main issue is, if i place my reusable functions there, they get run by default, without me calling them.

Comment: In this case, just make this TestCase abstract